# Igualar respuesta de servidor

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes estoy tratando de igualar las respuestas de mi servidor hacia al cliente esto para que, si la respuesta de mi servidor es igual a 2, aparezca un botón, al principio el botón es false. Mi servidor responde con un contador. Me pueden ayudar por favor, se los agradecería mucho

```
            byte[] TiraIn = new byte[10025];
        serverStream.Read(TiraIn, 0, 10024);
        string respuesta = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(TiraIn);

        msg("Resp.Server : " + respuesta);


        for(int i = 0; i < respuesta.Length; i++)
        {
            if (respuesta[i].Equals("2"))
            {
                button1.Visible = true;
                break;
            } else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    public void msg(string mesg)
    {
        txtRespuestaServidor.Text = txtRespuestaServidor.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + mesg;
    }
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema qué error tienes

Comment: No se muestra mi botón, ya debugee y nada

Comment: cuando debugeas que valor tenes en respuesta[i] ?

Comment: ¿Y porqué no cambias todo el **for** por un **if (respuesta.Contains("2")) { button1.Visible = true; }**?... Creo que el problema que tienes es que usas el Equals entre objetos de diferentes tipos, posiblemente Char y String y nunca cumple la condición... Tambien puedes probar sustituyendo el Equals por **==**.